# to collect awk output in while using pipe

Tags: shell, awk

**File is:**

```
12345,Collect
34522,Share
45221,Result
```

**Script:**

```
awk -F ',' '{print $1 $2}' file | while read -r first second
do
echo $first "and" $second
done
```

I'm trying to collect `$1` and `$2` in first and second variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `$1,$2` instead of `$1 $2`
otherwise awk will concate $1$2

```
awk -F ',' '{print $1,$2}' file | while read -r first second
do
echo $first "and" $second
done
```

I guess you are using `$first` `$second` for other processing tasks, however if you just want to print out some string, @Elliott Frisch's way is better

an sed way of printing it will be:

```
sed 's/,/ and /' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Please just use `{print $1 " and " $2}` like so,

```
$ cat file
12345,Collect
34522,Share
45221,Result
$ awk -F ',' '{print $1 " and " $2}' file
12345 and Collect
34522 and Share
45221 and Result
```

Comment: Yes true, but i'm more concerned about getting values in variable for while loop then about printing output

Comment: @user1502952 Why, you may do it all in one `awk` instead of splitting it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can do better without using `awk` at all.

```
IFS=,
while read -r first second; do
    echo $first and $second
done < file
unset IFS
```